# loading multiple popOver in the same view for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am a novice Ios developer and this a my first project which is ipad specific.I am having some issues with `UIPopOverControl` class implementation. In my project i have a `View controller` subclass and In that view i have several buttons . What I need to do is after pressing a button show a Popover with `UIPopOvercontrol` class.The data shown in the popover would be different for tapping  different button and all the data would be presented in `UITableView` style. I have been able to show one button and one popOver using one `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` subclass and loading data from a nib file. But how can I perform my desired task??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, not need to use multiple `UIPopoverViewController`, you can also do this by using single `UIPopoverViewController`.

simple create new Class of `UIPopoverViewController`;
and also create `UITableView` in `UIPopoverViewController`.

In your application you have multiple `UIButton`, just give `tag` of each buttons and pass your data base on `tag` of button, and display this data on `UITableView`.

Comment: 2 questions..1)can I use single UItableViewController subclass to show all different data in uitableview format and 2)I think i need to create UItableView programmetically not xib file right??

Comment: use only one UITableView in you popoverViewController, so data passed base on tag of UIButton. when you tapped specific button then you popOverView is created with single UITableView and you all data is display on UITableView. (data is related to tag of button).. :) and it is better to create UITableView programmetically, its my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

iOS purposely restricts having only one Popover visible at a time.  The API is intrinsically designed to prevent having multiple open at the same time.  You will need to consider an alternative approach that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I think i have not been clear enough . I don't need to load all popover at the same time. i need to use one popover after tapping one button but there will be multiple button and popover with different data in a same view

Answer (score 0):

I had made the requirement done here.
Check this out.
It will help you for sure.[Code for showing 2 popViewController at the same time and different data in both](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzzZTMV_F0BOQ1ZIQVVlYlRzOEk&usp=sharing)

You can set a variable in your AppDelegate to check which button is pressed?
Then, In viewWillAppear of your Controller, take the reference of that variable and check which button is pressed?

Then reload the data as per requirement in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Hope this helps

AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder

@property int buttonPressed; // Set this on click of any button

@end

YourController.h

int buttonPressed;

YourController.m

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

AppDelegate *app    =   (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
buttonPressed = app.buttonPressed;
```

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

if (buttonPressed == 1) { // do this}

else if (buttonPressed == 1) { // do this}

```
else  // do this
```

}

Comment: OP not need to show multiple UIPopoverViewController at same time , first read Question :) thanks